# Including MathJax.js with all the configuration files in the config file

Tags: javascript, config, mathjax

The common way to include MathJax.js is this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/js/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML,local/local"></script>
```

In the above way of inclusion the config files are specified in the config query parameter.
I'd just want to include the MathJax.js url without any query parameters passed
i.e The expected tag look should be :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/js/mathjax/MathJax.js"></script>
```

but still i would like to have it configured with the config files.

Is there a way that i can specify to included all the config files in mathjax/config directory or are there any other ways of including MathJax.js without the config passed as query params.

Comment: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in [config/default.js](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/config/default.js) in the MathJax github repo:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({

  //
  //  A comma-separated list of configuration files to load
  //  when MathJax starts up.  E.g., to define local macros, etc.
  //  The default directory is the MathJax/config directory.
  //  
  //  Example:    config: ["local/local.js"],
  //  Example:    config: ["local/local.js","MMLtoHTML.js"],
  //
  config: [],
  ...
});
```

By specifying that config parameter you can omit the query string in the script tag.